# Multi-line add-on for textarea

Tags: input, bootstrap-4, textarea

I'm using bootstrap 4 input-group and appending or pretending my inputs with add-ons as labels.
For the inputs its looking good. Now I need a multi-line add-on or label for text area.
I'm looking for best possible solution in Bootstrap or CSS.

Here is the code I'm trying.

```
    <style>
        .h-unset {
           height: unset !important;
        }
        .multiline-label {
           display: inline-block;
           word-wrap: break-word;
           word-break: break-word;
           width: 100%;
        }
    </style>

    <div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-3 row mx-0">
        <div class="input-group-prepend col-md-3 px-0">
            <label for="naastVastgoedbeleg-ging"
            class="input-group-text w-100 rounded-0 multiline-label h-unset"
            id="label-naastVastgoedbeleg-ging">
                <strong>Werkzaamheden naast vastgoedbeleg-ging (bijv. loondienst of onderneming)</strong>
            </label>
        </div>
        <textarea id="naastVastgoedbeleg-ging" 
        class="form-control rounded-0 col-md-9 h-unset" 
        aria-label="naastVastgoedbeleg-ging" 
        aria-describedby="label-naastVastgoedbeleg-ging">
        </textarea>
    </div>
```

Thankx for helping Happy Coding!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked by using this css

```
.multiline-label strong {
            white-space: pre-wrap;
        }
```